# Web API 2 - JWT with X509 certificate

Tags: c#, cryptography, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I got my JWT generation working with X509 and wanted to ask if you would recommend any changes in respect to:

- Signing certificate storing / handling.
- Publishing for anonymous access public key

Background info on service:

- Generating JWT with refresh token
- Expiration set in DB
- Certificate (*.cer) x509 is stored securely on Azure Blob
- Certificate (*.pfx) x509 is stored securely on Azure Blob

Here is piece of code I'm using to generate JWT:

```
var cert = _azureBlobService.DownloadFile("container", "certname.pfx");

X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2();
// Import from the byte array
myCert.Import(cert, "Password1", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(myCert.SubjectName.Name, 
    audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, 
    issued.Value.UtcDateTime, 
    expires.Value.UtcDateTime, 
    new X509SigningCredentials(myCert));

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

return jwt;
```